# Xcode 9 (9A235) iPhone X gone and strange Simulators: iPhone2017-A, -B -C?

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, xcode9, iphone-x

I just downloaded Xcode 9 trying to get some test on iPhone X. 
However it's really buggy. For some reason all my simulators are gone.. in both Xcode's(I have also Xcode 8 ofc. to be with stable).

So, in Xcode 9 I want to add iPhone X, but it's there. Only this list:

[image]

I've added strange iPhone2017-A and get this:

[image]

I just removed some unused simulators like old iPad.. after that iPhone X is gone, but I saw it was there..

How to restore it? Anyone else got the same issue?

Comment: Perhaps new devices coming up…ha. "Hey man, I got the new iPhone2017-C, wait was it the A?"

Comment: Which Xcode version do you have? Maybe you need to update to the GM.

Comment: I see the same thing on the GM, but it wasn't like that when I originally installed it. It said “iPhone X.”

Comment: Xcode 9.0.1 is out now and may fix the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah, iPhone2017-C is the iPhone X.

Comment: Xcode 9.1 Beta included updated simulator device type profiles that adjusted the name.

Answer (score 0):

If iPhone X simulator is not showing in simulators list. But iPhone2017-A, iPhone2017-B, iPhone2017-C are showing then you can use iPhone2017-C as a iPhone X simulator. 
-iPhone2017-C is the iPhone X.